# Scikit-Learn GradientBoostingRegressor min_impurity_decrease which value to set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

`Gbr1 = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state = 42,min_impurity_decrease= '??????')`
Which values should I try to set and what bounds has the min_impurity_decrease function?